# Validation not working on ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

Ok, I have a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class UserLogin
{
    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(UserLogin model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("Join", "User", FormMethod.Post); %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("ReturnUrl", Request.Url.AbsolutePath) %>

    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.EmailAddress, new { id = "join-emailaddress", @class = "text", uiHintText = "Email address" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.EmailAddress, "*") %>

    <%= Html.PasswordFor(c => c.Password, new { id = "join-password", @class = "text", uiHintText = "Password" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Password, "*")%>

    <%= Html.PasswordFor(c => c.PasswordConfirm, new { id = "join-password-confirm", @class = "text", uiHintText = "Password (repeat)" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.PasswordConfirm, "*")%>

    <input type="submit" value="Sign me up!" class="submit" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

If I post the form with nothing entered in any of the fields, I consistently get a value of 'true' for 'ModelState.IsValid'.

Shouldn't it be 'false', since I've marked those fields as 'Required' and not entered any values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the latest RC for ASP.NET MVC.  It includes some fixes for this.

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/04/aspnetmvc2-rc2.aspx

Specifically, from the release notes:

> **Default validation system validates entire model**
>  The default
>   validation system in ASP.NET MVC 1.0
>   and in previews of ASP.NET MVC 2 prior
>   to RC 2 validated only model
>   properties that were posted to the
>   server. In ASP.NET MVC 2 RC2, the new
>   behavior is that all model properties
>   are validated when the model is
>   validated, regardless of whether a new
>   value was posted.

For more information about this change, see the following posting on Brad Wilson’s blog:

**Input Validation vs. Model Validation in ASP.NET MVC**

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: I upgraded to ASP.NET MVC 2 RC 2, but I'm still having exactly the same problem. It doesn't seem like the upgrade has changed a thing.

Comment: I think it's fixed now, but a strange fix... See my comment under @H_Sampat's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem earlier, but I was using ASP.NET MVC1.
However I resolved the problem by adding the following code in Global.asax.vb file.

```
Sub Application_Start()
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

    'Added following line
    ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = New Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelBinder()        
End Sub
```

You'll need to import Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll. You can get it from http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471

Comment: Fixed! I added the following statement to the Application_Start function: ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder();. I wonder why this would have been necessary. Will look into it some more when I get time.

Comment: Ugh.. I was wrong. Ran the project a second time and it went back to giving me a 'true' for 'ModelState.IsValid'... I'll have to double-check all the changes I made and find out why it broke...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the cause of my particular problem.

When using the [Required] attribute on my ViewModel properties, I had specified a resource type and resource name for the error.

Example:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FirstNameError", 
          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResourceFile))]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

However I'd neglected to make the FirstNameError resource 'public'; it was still marked 'internal', and thus inaccessible.

After setting it public, everything worked and ModelState.IsValid contained a correct value.

I'm amazed that no errors were raised and this failed silently, but now I know why.

(Yes, I should have mentioned from the outset that I was using resources. I mistakenly thought this would be irrelevant but it turned out to be very relevant.)

Comment: Make sure you let Phil Haack know about this, if you think it's a bonafide bug. http://haacked.com/contact.aspx. Would be nice to get it into the final release.

Comment: Good idea! I've sent a message off to Phil.